# Can i implement wallet adapter for solana in vanilla js?

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, wallet, javascript

I would like to implement wallet adapter in a vanilla js script using something like unpkg or jsdlivr.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You might to move a few things around but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

i think [Jordan](https://twitter.com/jordaaash) could help u get an answer for this but i don't think there is any possible reasons for it to not get implemented unless there is a limitation from the browser or the extensions side.
If you would like to check the react implementation then it's here https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter